# Dar click en link <td >mandar la variable a PHP

Tags: php, script

De antemano gracias a todos aquellos que me quieran ayudar ya que tengo el siguiente detalle en mi codigo PHP. 
No se como enviar el valor "id2" a un SELECT que se encuentra en la misma pagina de PHP al dar un click en el icono. Este id2 cambia al seleccionar un  registro diferente todo bien, pero al darle click como la hago para que llegue a mi SELEC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto el objeto de poder mandar llamar un modal "#mimodalejemplo", cuando le doy un click en el icono de las 3 lineas horizontales me genera su ID imagen inferior en la pagina: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] .  Pero cuando muestra mi modal los campos estan en blanco ☹, no se ejecuta el SELECT.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro parte de mi codigo al dar un click toma un ID2 y ese valor llague a SELECT pero no se como hacer para que llegue :( .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

query($sql2);
    $row2 = $resultado2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, lo que ya entregó ya no lo va a modificar, para esto necesitas utilizar componentes de javascript que te permitan modificar el Select y alguna conectividad entre otro sitio que ejecute tu consulta de manera asíncrona como ajax.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo. no tendrás algún ejemplo para poder trabajar en ello.?

Comment: Gracias Jonathan Orta ya lo resolvi.. aqui hay puro culero que no ayuda